# Exception with @ElementCollection and the list of Strings

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the JavaEE application and using Hibernate 4.3.7.Final. In my DB there are two tables: RECHT(with columns: RECHT_RECHTEART(VARCHAR) and GEOB_ID(NUMBER) foreign key and no primary keys) and GESCHAEFTSOBJEKT where GEOB_ID is primary key

I am trying to put information from both tables in one entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GESCHAEFTSOBJEKT")
public class GeschaeftsobjektDTO extends AbstractDTO {

...

@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
@CollectionTable(
        name="RECHT",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="GEOB_ID")
)
@Column(name="RECHT_RECHTEART")
private List<String> geobRechte;
```

But I get exception during the deployment:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: GESCHAEFTSOBJEKT, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(geobRechte)]"}} ...
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your `@Id` mapping looks like? Are you using annotation on fields or getters? You can not combine those two.

Comment: @Rajendra Gujja, thank you, I really mess up two styles, this wasn't so clear from the exception, but you was absolutely right, fixing it helps me

Comment: I posted it as an answer, if your issue is fixed, please accept it. This is just to benefit someboday else, who may have the same issue and people don't read the comments that closely when they are searching for a solution :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your `@Id` mapping looks like? Are you using annotation on fields or getters? You can not combine those two.